# Using annotations to force method implementation

Tags: java, interface, annotations

Ok, this may be a silly question but I have to know for sure... I have a class which I need to annotate with a custom annotation. Also, this class has to implement a custom interface. Now the question: is there any way I can just annotate the class and then use the annotation ALSO like an interface for example forcing a method implementation? I think that is not possible but maybe there's a way... Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. You can eg. write an annotation processor which checks if a particular method has been implemented. At runtime you will have to check for the annotation and method using reflection if you're not implementing an interface. But this is acutually how most modern frameworks work these days (not forcing you to implement/ extend some specific interface/ class).

Answer (score 2):

No, because annotations are used to describe some meta-info and they are not used by compiler to define class types (and java as you know is strongly typed language).

The main issue will be in the next case:

```
public interface Hello{
  public void sayHello();
}

@Hello
public class HelloImpl{
  ... 
}

public class HelloService{
  public void perform (Hello hello) {}
}
```

So if your HelloImpl will not implement Hello interface, then in java there is no way to pass your HelloImpl in HelloService